# Material table action icons

Tags: material-table

The tick is that I have a custom action

```
actions={[
    {
        icon: () => <DeleteSharp color="primary" />,
        tooltip: 'Add icons to model items',
        onClick: (event, rowData) => {
            handleOpenDelete(rowData);
        }
    }
]}
```

And also editable

```
editable={{
    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
```

In my material table but I want the custom actions Icon appear after the edit one

this is how it looks now and shoud be reversed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHn2m.png)